# What kind of relationships are called n-ary relationships?

Tags: rdbms, diagram, entity-relationship

What kind of relationships are called n-ary relationships??

Comment: n-ary ones? But seriously, please explain what "n-ary" means, in plain English - it's not a standard term.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by the term "n-ary", but normally relationships that both sides can have many of the other are termed [`many to many`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_%28data_model%29) relationships and those that only one side does are termed [`one to many`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-to-many).